# Routing to a hard-coded Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This route mapping doesn't work:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "EnvironmentTargetsView",
    "api/EnvironmentTargetsView/{id}/{userGuid}",
    new
    {
     id = RouteParameter.Optional,
     userGuid = RouteParameter.Optional,
    });
```

I get the error: "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI"

However, this route mapping does work:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "EnvironmentTargetsView", "api/{Controller}/{id}/{userGuid}",
    new
    {
     Controller = "EnvironmentTargetsView",
     id = RouteParameter.Optional,
     userGuid = RouteParameter.Optional,
    });
```

I am curious about why and have surfed for answers on here, but can't really figure it out.  I want to hard-code that value because it is a specific route I want the API to take. My worry is by having it tokenised in the routeTemplate I can now not use a route with a similar pattern.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you specified:

```
Controller = "EnvironmentTargetsView"
```

in the second code block. If you add that to the first code block it'll work and still have a hard coded value.

You could also just add something like:

```
[Route("/api/EnvironmentTargetsView/{id}/{userGuid}]
public void Get(int id, guid userGuid) { }
```

To your controller methods.

Comment: Definitely the right answer for me, but still curious about why this might be. I ask because I have a second route mapped that does use the method I describe in my first block and it works successfully.

Comment: Well the router has no idea which controller to take based on only 'api/EnvironmentTargetsView', it's just a string. That's why there are defaults to give the router a hint. The second block should also work without the hint if EnvironmentTargetsViewController is the first found controller.